# Pytorch CNN, incompatible tensor shapes

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

Here is my pytorch CNN net. The input tensor is torch.Size([4, 1, 128, 128]) that represent images in batch size of 4:

```
class My_Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, image_length):

        self.image_length = image_length

        # Creating the layers here (convolutional, pooling, and linear layers)

        super(My_Net, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same')
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(10, 10))

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same')
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(8, 8))

        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(128, 50)

        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(50, 9)

    def forward(self, x):

        x = self.pool1(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))  # first convolution and pooling step with relu activation

        x = self.pool2(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))  # second convolution and pooling step with relu activation

        print(x.size()) #added this to see the tensor demensions before passing into the view and linear layers

        x = x.view((128 * 1 * 1, 4))  # second reshape

        x = F.relu(self.lin1(x))  # relu activation function on the first linear layer

        x = F.relu(self.lin2(x))  # we want only positive values so relu works best here

        return x
```

I'm getting an error in the forward pass that I am having a hard time fixing. I think it comes from a lack of understanding of how the dimensions are changing. The error is as follows:

```
line 51, in forward
    x = F.relu(self.lin1(x)) 

line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)

line 103, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

line 1848, in linear
    return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x4 and 128x50)
```

My main objective here is to send the images through 2 convolutional and pooling layers, then 2 linear layers ultimately reducing down to a 9 neuron linear layer that will be the output and compared via MSE to a set of 9 growth conditions for a given image. The output of the x.size() call in forward is torch.Size([4, 128, 1, 1])

Comment: Your reshape should be `x = x.view((x.shape[0], 128*1*1))`, as the feature dimension should be last.

Answer (score 0):

[Pytorch linear layers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) work with single instances and batched data very easily. If you are passing batched data, ensure that your data is shaped as `(batch_size, *)` where `*` is the dimension of your data. Your data should thus be of shape `(4, 128)` before passing it into your first linear layer. This you can do by reshaping, using `x = x.view((4, 128))`.

Additionally, it looks like the My_Net class is missing a call to the super() method in its **init** method. You should add this call so that the parent nn.Module class's **init** method is also called. This will properly initialize the nn.Module class and allow your network to function properly. Your **init** method should look like this:

```
def __init__(self, image_length):
    super(My_Net, self).__init__()  # Add this line
   
    # The rest of your net
```